# Swift: Closure and Clarification by example

Tags: swift, closures

Below is a class from a tutorial that I'm struggling to understand the syntax from.

```
import Foundation
class Board {
    private var cells: [BoardCellState]
    let boardSize = 8

    init () {
    cells = Array(count: boardSize * boardSize,
                    repeatedValue: BoardCellState.Empty)
    }


    subscript(location: BoardLocation) -> BoardCellState {
        get {
        assert(isWithinBounds(location), "row or column index out of bounds")
        return cells[location.row * boardSize + location.column]
        }
        set {
        assert(isWithinBounds(location), "row or column index out of bounds")
        cells[location.row * boardSize + location.column] = newValue
        }
    }


    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> BoardCellState {
        get {
        return self[BoardLocation(row: row, column: column)]
        }
            set {
            self[BoardLocation(row: row, column: column)] = newValue
            }
    }

    func isWithinBounds(location: BoardLocation) -> Bool {
        return location.row >= 0 && location.row < boardSize &&
        location.column >= 0 && location.column < boardSize
    }

    func cellVisitor(fn: (BoardLocation) ->()) {
            for column in 0..<boardSize {
            for row in 0..<boardSize {
            let location = BoardLocation(row: row, column: column)
            fn(location)
            }
            }
    }

    func clearBoard() {
                cellVisitor { self[$0] = .Empty }
    }
}
```

I need help with the last two functions:

```
    func cellVisitor(fn: (BoardLocation) ->()) {
            for column in 0..<boardSize {
            for row in 0..<boardSize {
            let location = BoardLocation(row: row, column: column)
            fn(location)
            }
            }
    }

    func clearBoard() {
                cellVisitor { self[$0] = .Empty }
    }
```

My understanding:

1. `cellVisitor` takes in a function that takes in an instance of `BoardLocation` and returns a `void`
2. Next, we iterate `column` through the values of `0` through `8`, and we nest it with iterating it through `0` through `8` for `row`.
3. This means with combined loops, we will we call the function `fn(location)` 64 times.

This is where I am lost.

**Question 1**:  Why are we calling the function `fn(location)` that was passed in and passing in `location` 64 times when there is nothing to return?

**Question 2**:  I don't really understand the purpose of `cellVisitor { self [$0] = .Empty }`.  `.Empty` is a value `0` from a `struct`.

**Question 3**: Does the shorthand `$0` mean set only the first element to `.Empty`?

Comment: This question is too broad to be marked as a duplicate of any single question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is this:

`func cellVisitor(fn: (BoardLocation) ->())` is a function that is called for each field of the 64. You can pass a closure or a function that does whatever you like for each field.

`cellVisitor { self [$0] = .Empty }` sets every element of the self to .Empty.

`self[]` is defined by the subscript. The argument in the square brackets is a particular board location.

$0 is a shortcut for the BoardLocation argument from here: `fn: (BoardLocation) ->()`

> Question 1: Why are we calling the function fn(location) that was
>   passed in and passing in location 64 times when there is nothing to
>   return?

For those 64 locations a function is called that sets the element to .Empty

> Question 2: I don't really understand the purpose of cellVisitor {
>   self [$0] = .Empty }. .Empty is a value 0 from a struct.

You are basically doing this:
`for each location in self[0...63] set location = .Empty`

> Question 3: Does the shorthand $0 mean set only the first element to
>   .Empty?

$0 is a shorthand for firs (and the only) argument of the function passed as a parameter.